# Pygame convert list of shapes to mask

Tags: pygame

The goal is to reveal an image in the background at the same time that a shape or a couple of shapes go through the screen. My approach is to create a list of shapes (rects or circles), then converting al that to a mask and then fill the screen all black but the masks every loop.

Is there a way to make a mask with a list of shapes? I checked pygame.mask (https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/mask.html?highlight=mask#module-pygame.mask) but cant see a way to convert list of shapes to mask. Any advice?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you can do is to create a `Mask` for each shape and one `Mask` to fill (cover) the entire screen.

Then, for each shape mask created this way, update the screen mask with `Mask.draw`, something like this:

```
    for rect, mask in surfaces:
        screen_mask.draw(mask, rect.topleft)
```

where `surfaces` is a list of `Rect`/`Mask` tuples.

Then you can use the screen mask to cover the screen, e.g. with `Mask.to_surface` like this:

```
new_background = screen_mask.to_surface(background.copy(), setsurface=background)
screen.blit(new_background, (0, 0))
```

where `background` is your original background image, `screen_mask` the mask that should cover the screen and `new_background` is the surface you draw instead of `background`.

---

Here's an example I hacked together; you'll get the idea:

```
import pygame, math

def main():
    d = 0
    pygame.init()
    screen = pygame.display.set_mode((640, 960))
    img = pygame.image.load('pexels-stijn-dijkstra-16745023.jpg').convert()
    
    triangle = pygame.Surface((32, 32))
    triangle.set_colorkey((0,0,0))
    pygame.draw.lines(triangle, 'red', True, ((0, 0), (32, 0), (16, 32)), 8)
    triangle_rect = triangle.get_frect(center=(400, 100))
    triangle_mask = pygame.mask.from_surface(triangle)

    circle = pygame.Surface((32, 32))
    circle.set_colorkey((0,0,0))
    pygame.draw.circle(circle, 'yellow', (16, 16), 16)
    pygame.draw.circle(circle, 'black', (16, 16), 12)
    circle_rect = circle.get_frect(center=(200, 400))
    circle_mask = pygame.mask.from_surface(circle)
    
    surfaces = (
        (triangle, triangle_rect, triangle_rect, triangle_mask), 
        (circle, circle_rect, circle_rect, circle_mask)
    )

    cloack = pygame.mask.Mask((640, 960))
    clock = pygame.time.Clock()
    while True:
        for e in pygame.event.get():
            if e.type == pygame.QUIT or e.type == pygame.KEYDOWN and e.key == pygame.K_ESCAPE:
                return

        for surface, rect, base, mask in surfaces:
            cloack.draw(mask, rect.topleft)
            rect.x = base.x + math.sin(0.01 * pygame.time.get_ticks()) * 10
            rect.y += 0.5
            
        back = cloack.to_surface(img.copy(), setsurface=img)
        screen.blit(back, (0, 0))

        for surface, rect, base, mask in surfaces:
            screen.blit(surface, rect)

        pygame.display.flip()
        d = clock.tick(60)
        
main()
```

[image]